# ansible with solidfire for netapp

Tags: python, ansible, netapp

I have a sample netapp playbook

```
 ---
    - hosts: all
      gather_facts: False
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      become_method: sudo

      tasks:
        - name: Start restore
          na_elementsw_snapshot_restore:
            hostname: "{{ip_adr}}"
            username: "{{username}}"
            password: ""
            account_id: ansible-1
            src_snapshot_id: snapshot_20171021
            src_volume_id: volume-playarea
            dest_volume_name: dest-volume-area
```

and this inventory file

```
 snaptest ansible_host=192.168.1.10 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=centos ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/slenz/.ssh/id_vm_sync ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2.7


[snap]
snaptest
```

when I run the playbook I get

```
 fatal: [snaptest]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "the python SolidFire SDK module is required"}
```

However I did install solidfire via pip

```
 Requirement already satisfied: solidfire-sdk-python in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.5.0.87)
 Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=19.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from solidfire-sdk-python) (41.0.1)
 Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.15.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from solidfire-sdk-python) (0.17.1)
 Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.1.6 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from solidfire-sdk-python) (1.1.6)
 Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from solidfire-sdk-python) (2.22.0)
 Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->solidfire-sdk-python) (3.0.4)
 Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->solidfire-sdk-python) (2.8)
 Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->solidfire-sdk-python) (1.25.3)
 Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->solidfire-sdk-python) (2019.3.9)
```

Now my question is why the ansible doesn't find the solidfire. I can open a python cli and do "import solidfire.common" and that works.

I am using ansible 2.8.0, centos7 and python 2.7.5

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `ansible --version` => make sure that ansible is using the python version for which you installed your libraries.

Comment: The documentation says "[The requirements are needed on the host that executes this module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/na_elementsw_snapshot_restore_module.html#na-elementsw-snapshot-restore-netapp-element-software-restore-snapshot)". I bet on **the host that executes this module** is the remote system.

Comment: I installed it on both just to make sure.
It is using the right version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one module that returns `the python SolidFire SDK module is required` message.

It's the [ansible/module_utils/netapp.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/26d87a912b4b68c8a72a47e7a8a93c434bd06402/lib/ansible/module_utils/netapp.py) module.

The condition that returns this error message (if false) is:

`if HAS_SF_SDK and hostname and username and password:`

So if your `password` field is empty (`""` is considered false by Python), you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the section before `tasks`. 
`localsf` is my local SolidFire MVIP in /etc/ansible/hosts. You don't need to sudo in order to use SolidFire Python SDK and connect to MVIP.

```
- name: NetApp Element Software Snapshot-to-Volume 
  hosts: localsf
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
```

Next, `account_id: ansible-1`: there's no such account ID. 
ID's are integers, not strings. You probably meant `account_id: 1`.

Last but not least, the empty password value.